# notepad++ v6.6.9 window frames for function list and document map

Tags: notepad++

I am recently using the notepad++ v6.6.9 and the new features function list and document map are amazing. However, I accidentally dragged the embedded window frame out and moved to some other place. 
My silly question is: how can I put the document map or function list window back to the east(right) side embedded to the whole frame. The only way for the document map or function list frame to be embedded is on the north(top) side and when I restart it, it still keeps the same.

Comment: If you click and hold down the mouse where it says `Document Map`, you can drag it to the position you want. If you move it right over to the right of the screen it will dock to that side.

Comment: I get it, so silly of me, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem at all :)